# jit-grunt: Plugin for the "watch" task not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

after executing >> "grunt server" i saw these errors i don't know what and where i need to attach or detach some code.
one more thing DeprecationWarning:  while nowhere in the code i wrote `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk`.

```
$ grunt server
Running "server" task
>> The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.

Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "env:all" (env) task

Running "express:dev" (express) task
Starting background Express server
(node:5497) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
Stopping Express server

Running "wait" task
>> Waiting for server reload...
Done waiting!

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "watch" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "watch" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2018-09-25 12:24:48 UTC+5:30)
loading tasks  124ms  ▇▇▇▇ 7%
express:dev    106ms  ▇▇▇ 6%
wait            1.5s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 85%
Total 1.8s
```

> **Solution**
>   npm install grunt-contrib --save-dev
>   and add this line before the last line of grunt.js:
>   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');